# Is there an easy way to implement AutoResetEvent in C++0x?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, autoresetevent

I understand I've asked this question before: [What is the C++ equivalent for AutoResetEvent under Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128221/what-is-the-c-equivalent-for-autoresetevent-under-linux)

However, I'm learning that in C++0x, the threading library are made much simpler, so I want to pose this question out again, is there an easy way to implement AutoResetEvent in C++0x?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a translation of the [accepted answer to your first question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8129037/576911) to use C++11 tools:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <stdio.h>

class AutoResetEvent
{
  public:
  explicit AutoResetEvent(bool initial = false);

  void Set();
  void Reset();

  bool WaitOne();

  private:
  AutoResetEvent(const AutoResetEvent&);
  AutoResetEvent& operator=(const AutoResetEvent&); // non-copyable
  bool flag_;
  std::mutex protect_;
  std::condition_variable signal_;
};

AutoResetEvent::AutoResetEvent(bool initial)
: flag_(initial)
{
}

void AutoResetEvent::Set()
{
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> _(protect_);
  flag_ = true;
  signal_.notify_one();
}

void AutoResetEvent::Reset()
{
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> _(protect_);
  flag_ = false;
}

bool AutoResetEvent::WaitOne()
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(protect_);
  while( !flag_ ) // prevent spurious wakeups from doing harm
    signal_.wait(lk);
  flag_ = false; // waiting resets the flag
  return true;
}


AutoResetEvent event;

void otherthread()
{
  event.WaitOne();
  printf("Hello from other thread!\n");
}


int main()
{
  std::thread h(otherthread);
  printf("Hello from the first thread\n");
  event.Set();

  h.join();
}
```

Output:

```
Hello from the first thread
Hello from other thread!
```

**Update**

In the comments below [tobsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27083/tobsen) notes that `AutoResetEvent` has the semantics of `signal_.notify_all()` instead of `signal_.notify_one()`.  I haven't changed the code because the [accepted answer to the first question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8129037/576911) used `pthread_cond_signal` as opposed to `pthread_cond_broadcast` and I am leading with the statement that this is a faithful translation of that answer.

Comment: In fact, is can produce a deadlock if Set is executed before WaitOne (as explained in the answer to the question linked in this answer)

Comment: Works fine. No chance of deadlocks thanks to `bool flag_` and [how `wait()` works with `std::unique_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait).

Comment: you might want to change `signal_.notify_one();` to `signal_.notify_all();` to reflect the behaviour of the `AutoResetEvent` Class OP refers to.

Comment: @tobsen: Thanks!  I've updated my answer with this information.

Comment: Is it OK that flag_ is not atomic?

Comment: Yes.  `flag_` is always read and written under the protection of the mutex, and thus need not be (and should not be) atomic.

Comment: The one thing Howard's execellent response left out was WaitOne(w/Timeout). So I got the idea for this from C++ Concurrency In Action: pg 91 (Chap. 4 Sync Concur oper).                                      <code>bool AutoResetEvent::WaitOne(uint32_t timeToWaitMs)
{
 namespace chr = std::chrono;
 auto const timeout = chr::steady_clock::now() + chr::milliseconds(timeToWaitMs);
 std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
 while (!done)
 {
  if (signal.wait_until(lk, timeout) == std::cv_status::timeout)
   break;
 }
 return done;
}</code>

Comment: `bool AutoResetEvent::WaitOne(uint32_t timeToWaitMs)
{
 namespace chr = std::chrono;
 auto const timeout = chr::steady_clock::now() + chr::milliseconds(timeToWaitMs);
 std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
 while (!_flag)
 {
  if (signal.wait_until(lk, timeout) == std::cv_status::timeout)
   break;
 }
 return _flag;
}`