# thread handling c++ linux OS

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, mutex

I have three functions in my project written in c++. They are in the same .cpp file and I have two header files.

Now, I have three corresponding threads so that, the second thread takes the output from the first thread,and the last thread waits until the second thread end its operations.note that the threads are with in a "forever loop" i.e. `while(1){....}`

source.cpp looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "source.h"
#include "glob_variables.h"
#include "armadillo"
#include <vector>
using namespace arma;
using namespace std;

void source::first_function(int size)
{
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
  {
   container.push_back(i);//container is global variable vector of type int declared in glob_variables.h
  }
}
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
void source::second_function()
{
   //sleep until the first function fills the the vector to set set its size to matrix.n_rows 
  matrix.set_size(container.size(),33);
   for(int i=0;i<container.size();i++)
   {
    for(int j=0;j<50;j++)
     {
       matrix(i,j)=i+j;//matrix is also a global variable in glob_variables.h
     }
   }
}
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
void source::third_function()
{
//sleep untill the second function fills the matrix, then print
cout<<matrix;//print out the matrix
}
```

source.h:

```
#include "glob_variables.h"
#include "armadillo"
#include <vector>
using namespace arma;
using namespace std;
class source
{
public:
 void first_function(int size);
 void second_function();
 void third_function();
};
```

glob_variables.h:

```
#include "armadillo"
#include <vector>
using namespace arma;
using namespace std;

extern mat matrix;
extern vector<int> container;
```

Main.cpp:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include "source.h"
    #include "glob_variables.h"
    #include "armadillo"
    #include <vector>
    using namespace arma;
    using namespace std;

//thread functions
     void* first_reader(void* id1)
     {
       source mysource;
       while(1)
       {
         mysource.first_function(80);
       }
     }

     void* second_reader(void* id2)
     {
       source mysource;
       while(1)
       {
         mysource.second_function();
       }
     }

     void* third_reader(void* id3)
     {
       source mysource;
       while(1)
       {
        mysource.third_function();
       }
     }

   int main()
   {
    pthread_t first;
    pthread_t second;
    pthread_t third;

    int hndl_first;
    int hndl_second;
    int hndl_third;

    hndl_first = pthread_create(&first, NULL, first_reader, NULL);
    hndl_second= pthread_create(&second, NULL, second_thread, NULL);
    hndl_third;= pthread_create(&third, NULL,third_thread, NULL);

   pthread_exit(NULL);
   return 0; 
   }
```

Can I have any techniques to do this, or any simple example. Thanks.

Comment: Any reason for why you are using pthreads and not boost?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following link. An AutoResetEvent fulfills your requirement. The code in the link is exactly what you expect.

[What is the C++ equivalent for AutoResetEvent under Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128221/what-is-the-c-equivalent-for-autoresetevent-under-linux)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to play thread sequentially.
Do something in first thread -> do something in second thread -> do something in third thread.

Is it right? 
In this case you can use signal.

example:

```
pthread_cond_t cond;
pthread_mutex_t mtx;

typedef enum {
    ready1,
    ready2,
    ready3
} thread_ready;

thread_ready t_ready;

void* first_reader(void* id1)
{
    //source mysource;
    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
        while(t_ready != ready1)
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mtx);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);

        std::cout << "first" << std::endl;
        //mysource.first_function(80);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
        t_ready = ready2;
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);

        sleep(1);

    }
}


void* second_reader(void* id2)
{
    //source mysource;
    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
        while(t_ready != ready2)
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mtx);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);

        std::cout << "second" << std::endl;
        //mysource.second_function();

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
        t_ready = ready3;
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);

        sleep(1);
    }
}

void* third_reader(void* id3)
{
    //source mysource;
    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
        while(t_ready != ready3)
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mtx);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);

        std::cout << "third" << std::endl;
        //mysource.third_function();

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
        t_ready = ready1;
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);

        sleep(1);
    }
}


int main()
{
    pthread_t first;
    pthread_t second;
    pthread_t third;

    int hndl_first;
    int hndl_second;
    int hndl_third;

    pthread_cond_init(&cond,NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mtx,NULL);

    t_ready = ready1;

    hndl_first = pthread_create(&first, NULL, first_reader, NULL);
    hndl_second = pthread_create(&second, NULL, second_reader, NULL);
    hndl_third = pthread_create(&third, NULL,third_reader, NULL);

    pthread_join(first, NULL);
    pthread_join(second, NULL);
    pthread_join(third, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Actually this case doesn`t have to make 3 thread. If you want do like my code, you better make just 1 thread.