# Do Wait Handles release locks that a thread acquires?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

When I have code as shown below, my question is if the thread that calls signal.WaitOne release the lock that is has acquired for another thread to acquire the lock? I assume this is a trivial question to ask, but I tried searching for something like this and came up empty. If someone could shed some light on this and modify my post/title to make it more searchable for anyone looking for this in the future, I'd appreciate it greatly.

```
AutoResetEvent signal = new AutoResetEvent(false);

foo() {
  Monitor.Enter(locker);
  try {
       // code

       if(condition)
          signal.WaitOne();

       // code         
  } finally {
      Monitor.Exit(locker);
  }
}
```

Edit: I am making this edit for future reference:

It seems like a better paradigm for what I am trying to do is this:

```
foo() {
  Monitor.Enter(locker);
  try {
       // code

       while(condition)
          Monitor.Wait(locker);

       // code         
  } finally {
      Monitor.Exit(locker);
  }
}

bar {
  lock(locker) {
      Monitor.Pulse(locker);
  }
}
```

Comment: `signal.WaitOne` has no effect on what `Monitor` does...

Comment: Hi @PeterRitchie - I have made an edit for future reference. I'd appreciate it if you could ratify the edit.

Comment: In .NET 4.0 they added a new [Monitor.Enter(obj, ref lockTacken)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289498.aspx). You should use it instead of the `Monitor.Enter(obj)`

Comment: FYI, wait handles are not part of C#. They are part of .NET.

Comment: @xanatos - Thanks for the pointer to the overloaded version. I read up on how to use it and it is very useful. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Noted. Thanks for your comment. I only mentioned C# because that's the language I am using handles mechanisms with. So you're saying that wait handles are part of .NET but Monitor.Wait and Monitor.Pulse are part of the language? Or are all multithreading mechanisms part of the .NET framework? I apologize if I am not being very clear, I am just trying to understand where the line between the language and the .NET framework is drawn.

Comment: It always shocks me to hear about people who don't know the difference between a programming language and a framework. Try this experiment: remove all of the "System.*" references and build. The errors are part of the framework.

Comment: Hi @JohnSaunders - Thanks a lot! I do admit the line between language and framework is a little blurred in my mind. I looked up the C# language specification vs. the Java language specification(that I'm more at home with) and I must also remark that, to me, the C# specification makes a more clear distinction between language and framework than the JLS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The lock is held until `Exit` is called. Generally, you should try not to block while holding a lock. It increases the chances of a deadlock.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Appreciate it.

Comment: Hi @mike_z. I made an edit for future reference. I'd appreciate it if you could ratify it. Thanks.

Comment: @Sandman I'm not entirely familiar with the correct usage of `Pulse`/`Wait`, but I did make one correction. Also, the `lock` keyword does the work of your `Enter`/`Exit` with a try/finally.

Comment: Thanks for your fix. Silly of me not to have seen that earlier.